# selectinput list then enter value for numericinput in shiny

Tags: shiny

Is it possible to link selectinput and numericinput in shiny? I want for the user of the app to select something from selectInput, then enter a value for that specific selection. Each variable in the list would have a numericinput to enter. Ultimately, the values would be registered in a datatable. Selecting more variables would simply require clicking a button. My knowledge of shiny is limited and this is all I was able to muster, please advise.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("solvent", "Choose a solvent:",
                list(`Solvent` = c("ETOH", "SALINE", "DW5",'CREMOPHOR','WATER','DMSO','2% KLUCEL (pH=4 /w HCl)')
    )),
    actionButton('add','Add'),
    numericInput('vol_ETOH','Vol ETOH (ml)',0),
    numericInput('vol_SALINE','Vol SALINE (ml)',0),
    numericInput('vol_DW5','Vol DW5 (ml)',0),
    numericInput('vol_CREMOPHOR','Vol CREMOPHOR (ml)',0),
    numericInput('vol_WATER','Vol WATER (ml)',0),
    numericInput('vol_DMSO','Vol DMSO (ml)',0),
    numericInput('vol_KLUCEL','Vol 2% KLUCEL (ml)',0),
    textOutput("result"),
    dataTableOutput('table')
)
  server = function(input, output) {
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$solvent,{rv$data<-data.frame(vol1=input$solvent,vol=input$vol_ETOH)})
    output$table<-renderDataTable({ rv$data})

    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$solvent)
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the application is supposed to react. I think however that changing the `observeEvent` line to `observeEvent(input$add, {
    rv$data <- data.frame(rbind(rv$data, c(vol1 = input$solvent, vol = input$vol_ETOH)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  })` leads to the expected result. I.e. the app listens for the actionbutton _add_ and appends the selection to the data.frame.

Comment: Thanks Juergen for your suggestion. However, I would like for the input$solvent to be the column name and then the value entered to be added down the column (new row for each value). Is this possible? Is there a way to simply have one dropdown list and one numeric input that would change according to what the user selects in the dropdown list?